Help: DC op-amp integrator starts at saturation instead of zero!
I'm having an issue with my integrator circuit where the output immediately starts at saturation instead of zero. I want the integrator to start at zero and then linearly move towards saturation, as predicted by theory.
I suspect the problem might be related to the initial charge on the capacitor, which should ideally start with a voltage of zero. However, I’m unsure how to configure the circuit to ensure that the capacitor's initial voltage is zero in my simulation.
Here’s what happens:

At the start, the output is already at saturation, which is not the desired behavior.
When I move the switch to a different position, I observe the correct linear behavior, where the output voltage linearly increases towards saturation (positive saturation).

Question:  how should I configure my circuit or simulation to ensure the integrator starts at zero? Is there a specific way to discharge the capacitor initially or any other method to achieve this?
Simulation results:
At the start:


After moving the switch:


No op amp is ideal. But the 741 is about the least ideal you can possibly get while still technically counting as an op amp. Please don't use a 741.

Your real-life circuit will actually start at 0V output, assuming it has been un-powered long enough for C1 to discharge. That's because real-life circuits don't do a DC operating point analysis prior to "kicking off".
Your simulator, though, does do a DC operating point analysis, which establishes initial DC "quiescent" conditions such as capacitor voltages and inductor currents, as a starting point for the time-domain simulation thereafter. In essence, the simulator has some idea of voltages and currents present before time starts rolling, and uses them to estimate how the circuit would have already settled, as if it had been running for years already.
The state of S1 at time \$t=0\$ presents +1V to the integrator, and the simulator assumes it's been like that forever, which is why the initial DC state has C1 fully charged.
Switch off the initial DC operating point analysis when performing a transient (time-domain) simulation, to have all capacitors with no initial charge, and all inductors with no initial magnetic field.
Edit: Apparently your simulator is NI Multisim. Table 1 on this page describes the options available to you when performing a transient analysis. Option 1, "set to zero", sounds exactly like the "skip initial conditions" situation I described above. Option 3 is what spice and CircuitLab do by default.
This is the dialog option you should change (taken from the same page):

Other simulators have similar features. For example, in CircuitLab, the time-domain simulation dialog box has an option "Skip initial":

In spice-based simulators like ngspice and LTspice, the simulation directive ".tran" takes an argument uic to suppress the initial DC operating point analysis:
.tran 0 1m 1u uic
That can be done for you in the LTSpice simulation dialog:

I can't tell you how to do this in your own simulator, because I have no idea what it is.

Simulator should normally have an option to set capacitor initial voltage. If not, you could use a switch across the capacitor which is closed until t=0 and then, opens at t=0+

In the simulation, replace the input switch with a generator and start a transient analysis with zero initial values.

You can also connect a high value resistor in parallel with the capacitor, in which case the signal waveform doesn't change.


Thanks for some of your suggestions. I opted to ground the rails at the start so that it doesn't go to saturation. And then I powered the rails later using the switches s4 and s5. It seems to work now. Here are the results:

Output result:


As was pointed out, this step would probably be unnecessary in an actual physical construction of the circuit.
